# Blinking CSS3 color animation using steps don't work as expected

Tags: css, css-animations

I have css3 animation of blinking cursor like this:

```
.cmd {
    font-family: FreeMono, monospace;
    color: #aaa;
    background-color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
}
.cmd .cursor {
    animation: blink 1s infinite steps(2, start);
}
@keyframes blink {
    to {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

I need to animate color because I want to show letters inside cursor.

If I use `steps(2, end)` it's not fully black and if I use `steps(2, start)` it's not fully white. How can I fix it?

Here is [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zodib/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: @Adrift no you don't need to, if you don't use `from{}` it's generated automatically. But If I use `from{}` I have the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work [**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/zodib/13/edit)

```
.cmd .cursor {
    -webkit-animation: blink 1s infinite steps(1, start);

}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  0%,100%{
        background-color: #000;
        color: #aaa;
  }
  50% {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #aaa;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't I use `50% {
        background-color: #aaa;
        color: #000;
  }` but it work if I change bg color to `#bbb;` or `#aab;`?

Comment: You can use anything. For a seamless continuous animation, it should be 0% to 50% and then to 100% i.e. 0% and 100% should be the same. In case of rotation, it works from 0 to 100 because 0 and 100 are the same i.e. 0deg = 360deg.

Comment: When I use bg color `#aaa` I don't see the letter inside the cursor if it's black. but when I change that color a bit, it appear. Maybe it's a browser bug.

Comment: It seems that this don't happen in FireFox.

Comment: okay can you post the same code in jsfiddle? this jsbin is making unnecessary versions and I can't seem to find your version.

Comment: Thanks, your solution work, but I use `50% {
        background-color: #bbb;
        color: #000;
  }` in my code.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? http://jsfiddle.net/a2AaF/2/
And I can't seem to understand the problem but tell you what, if somehow, bgcolor and text color get same during animation, you won't be able to see.

Comment: It look weird. In chromium the cursor is full black, and in FF the the color on gray background is not black.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to finish the animation earlier than the time step will arrive

```
animation: blink 1s infinite steps(1, end)
```

...

```
keyframes blink {
    30% {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #aaa;
    }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/zodib/12/edit
You can play around with percentage+number of steps, to get the timing you desire

Comment: Don't work, If I use 30% I've got 3 steps animation even if I have steps(2).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention `steps(1, end)` is also necessary for this to work. Will update answer

Comment: I've tested it with `steps(1, start)` and it don't work. It blinking but when cursor is black I've don't see leter (the color is not set to `#aaa`).

Comment: it's `steps(1, end)`, I'm being clumsy today. check out the link in answer